# Camera Streaming through AVshws driver

Tags: directshow

Recently I have built a virtual camera filter using Vivek's VCam (http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm) in directshow but it works only in softwares which can show user mode filters. So to make my virtual device available in all softwares I have to built a kernel mode driver.

I have two questions.

Can I somehow overcome this problem with user mode directshow filter?

If not how can I get camera streaming through AVStream avshws driver available in WDK sample drivers or if there is anyother easy solution for it then please suggest?

Comment: I don't think this is your problem. I think that your virtual cam is not listed with  software that uses Media Foundation for capture. You'll have to build a Media Foundation based virtual camera.

Comment: I am holding this project for now but does not the WDM drivers appear in every camera streaming tool? I checked with the sample driver of avshws in WDK and it appeared everywhere.

Comment: It depends on whether the tool uses Media Foundation or Directshow